# Django conditional annotation - annotating value of Max(item__created_at) value

Tags: python, django, annotations, conditional-statements

I'm a bit stuck on what the best and correct way to do a conditional annotation of this sort is.

What I have are Conversations and Messages with a many 2 many relationship - Conversations can have multiple messages.

What I need to do is annotate 2 things - the latest message timestamp and the latest message text so that I can display them for our users.

I'm currently stuck at the following query:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Conversation.objects \
        .prefetch_related('messages') \
        .annotate(
            last_timestamp=Max('messages__created_at'),
            last_text=Case(
                When(
                    messages__created_at=Max('messages__created_at'),
                    then='messages__body'
                )
            )
        ) \
        .order_by('-last_timestamp')
```

Now the first annotation - `last_timestamp` one works - it's a simple annotation. Sadly the second one only works when there is only one messages which kind of makes sense looking at the resulting SQL.

```
SELECT 
    `pkm_twilio_conversation`.`created_at`,
    `pkm_twilio_conversation`.`updated_at`,
    `pkm_twilio_conversation`.`conversation_id`,
    `pkm_twilio_conversation`.`conversation_name`,
    CASE
        WHEN `pkm_twilio_message`.`created_at` = (
            MAX(
                `pkm_twilio_message`.`created_at`
            )
        ) 
        THEN `pkm_twilio_message`.`body` 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS `last_message`,
    MAX(
        `pkm_twilio_message`.`created_at`
    ) AS `last_timestamp` 
FROM
    `pkm_twilio_conversation` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `pkm_twilio_message` 
        ON (
            `pkm_twilio_conversation`.`conversation_id` = `pkm_twilio_message`.`conversation_id`
        ) 
GROUP BY `pkm_twilio_conversation`.`conversation_id` 
ORDER BY `last_timestamp` DESC
```

The question is - what is the best "django way" to achieve this? I need the value of the latest message annotated properly. Or should I use multiple queries and value list?

Comment: This works for me. Just to be sure, shouldn't `then='messages_body'` be `then='messages__body'`?

(I say this works for me, only I don't have a m2m relation, but a fk from the equivalent of messages to conversation)

Comment: @BjörnKristinsson Yes I corrected the mistake in the post. It is indeed 'messages__body'. The problem I'm having is that it only works if the conversation has 1 message. If it has more than 1 message the "when" doesn't kick in and last_message is None.

Comment: Strange, this seems to be working for me, but of course I don't have the exact same model structure. Your SQL looks a bit suspect, I thought you needed the aggregation columns in the GROUP BY as well, ``pkm_twilio_message`.`created_at`` in your case. What DB backend are you using?

Comment: Hmm I'm using InnoDB version 5.6.23

The objects I have are Conversation and Message and Message has a foreign key pointing at the conversation it belongs to. 

It's a pretty standard m2m relationship and this really should work so it's weird that it doesn't. 

It's really strange because I am getting the last message ONLY if it's the only message. So conversations with a single message work fine. It's probably something to do with my case/when statement

PS This is annotation not aggregation